# Place menu items in a dropdown if they break down into a new row

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering how it would be possible to place menu items that break down into a new row because of window resizing/small screen into a dropdown instead, preferably without the use of CSS media queries. The menu itself is 100% width.

Like this:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <a href=""><li>Item 1</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>Item 2</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>Item 3</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>Item 4</li></a>
        <a href=""><li>Item 5</li></a>
        <li class="drop">
            <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
            <div class="dropdown" style="top:77px;">
                <ul>
                    <! -- This is the dropdown the menu items should be placed in -->
                    <a href=""><li>Item 6</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is called the _priority+ navigation pattern_ - use that as search keyword.

Comment: I didn't know what keywords to use for this, so thanks, will look into it!